# How to get text file from external storage in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an app in which the user should be able to get a txt file from there external storage in order to upload to firebase_storage. The thing is, I don't know the path of the file, so I want the user to be able to choose this like they would be able to choose a pdf using file_picker or pick an image using image_picker? How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can use the flutter_document_picker and specify in that that I want a txt file for the device to get.